# Understanding a product of objects as a limit of a discrete diagram

Tags: category-theory, definition, limits-colimits, additive-categories

I have read that a product of objects $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ in a category $\mathcal{A}$ can be defined as a limit of a discrete diagram i.e. a diagram $D:\mathcal{I}\to\mathcal{A}$ where the only morphisms in $\mathcal{I}$ are the identity morphisms.

So if we define $\mathcal{I}$ to be the discrete category whose objects are the elements of the set $I$, and where $D(i):=A_i$ for each $i\in I$, then the limit of this diagram will be $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ with the projections $\pi_i:\prod_{j\in I}A_j\to A_i$.

However, consider the following: Let $D$ be a discrete diagram in **Set** that has a limit and where the objects form a proper class. Then the limit is a product $\prod_i D_i$ indexed over a proper class, rather than a set. My understanding of taking arbitrary products of sets is that it must be indexed by a set, yet the definition here seems to include proper classes. Am I missing something?

EDIT: In other words, a [product of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_Cartesian_products) involves using an index **set**, whereas the category theory definition of a product seems to allow for indexing by proper classes, unless we restrict to discrete diagrams that are also small.

Comment: The category of sets has all *small* limits, where small means that the diagram $D$ is a small category. In particular $D$ has a set of objects. Most large diagrams in Set just don't have limits.

Comment: So the category of sets does not have all limits of discrete diagrams, just small discrete diagrams? I get the impression that a category having all limits would be very unusual.

Comment: Correct. In fact, if a category has all products (limits of all discrete diagrams, not just small ones), then it is a preorder! (Meaning there is at most one arrow between any two objects.) If I've answered your question in the comments, I can turn my comments into an answer along with a reference to a proof of this fact about preorders.

Comment: Yes, you have pretty much completely answered my question. Essentially I was just trying to reconcile the ordinary set-theoretic definition of an arbitrary Cartesian product with the 'limit of discrete diagram' category theory one. If the category of sets does not admit arbitrary (categorical) products then this makes sense :)

Comment: Usually people only really talk about limits and colimits of small diagrams, since they hardly ever exist for large diagrams.  So, when people talk about categories having limits or colimits, they almost always mean only small limits or colimits.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks, I didn't realise this. Since I'm working predominantly with a bunch of concrete categories in homotopy theory, do you think it would be worth redefining diagrams to be small to cut the 'large diagrams' stuff out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The category of sets has all small limits, where small means that the diagram $D$ is a small category. In particular $D$ has a set of objects, so the notion of "limit of small discrete category $D$" agrees with the notion of "product of a set-indexed family of sets".

Most large diagrams in Set just don't have limits. In fact, if a category has all products, by which I mean limits of all discrete diagrams, not just small ones, then it is a preorder! (Meaning there is at most one arrow between any two objects.) See Theorem 2.1 of Mike Shulman's [Set Theory for Category Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1279) for the quick argument, and lots of other enlightening discussion.

As Eric Wofsey notes in the comments, usually people only talk about small diagrams. In particular, the terms "complete category" and "cocomplete category" mean that the category has all *small* limits and colimits, respectively.